# Remove dash from blog title wordpress

Tags: php, wp-title

Hi this is my first time using wordpress and php, I created a static page for my front page of the site, and got my news on a separate section, I'm just wondering how do i remove the the dash from the wordpress title in the blog. I understand that its trying pull through the page number, but now that's not required I just need to remove the dash fromwp_title. Sorry if this post is a duplicate, as I couldn't find any information regarding this topic.

Comment: What exactly are you calling "the title"?  The actual HTML ~<title>~ element in the page source?  Are you using an off-the-shelf theme or are you developing a custom theme?   Provide more detail in your question or add the code from your header.php if relevant, etc.

Comment: If you have Yoast plugin installed, check the settings, It might be the SEO title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite trivial in general case, since it varies depending on title implementation by *specific theme*.

The historical way has been [`wp_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) call in theme's template. The newer method is hook–based [Title Tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag).

So it is hard to say specifically without knowing/seeing code of a specific theme.

This is one of the reasons for high popularity of SEO plugins, for many of which manipulating titles in more user–centric ways is one of the main features.